# Driving through a puddle

Tags: chevrolet, air-intake, cruze

I have already asked a question on this board but I have another question. Sorry I am not good with cars so I don't know the lingo.I have a 2017 Chevy cruze. I drove through a deep puddle at about 40 mph and I am now having problems with the car. My car now has an engine light on and when I first start the car, the engine sounds really loud then calms down and is quiet after a few seconds. I noticed the rpm needle bouncing a bit. I am still able to drive the car but it is slow and will not go over 3 rpm. I took it to a mechanic and he did a quick check on my car and found a tube to be ripped so we had to order a new part and we are awaiting the shipment to get it repaired (I will insert the pic). The tube seems to go from the bottom and wraps around into the engine. I am really scared that I ruined my new car and want some advice or reassurance until the part comes in. My questions are:

1 - Could this tube that is broken be causing the loud engine noise and bouncing rpm needle? The engine is only loud the first few seconds
2 - I am really worried about the fact that I could have possibly ruined anything electrical in the car. Since I am able to start the car and drive it, did I luck out and could the electrical system possibly be fine? After going through the puddle it sputtered a bit but was fine and able to drive me about 30 miles back home.

[image]

Comment: Relax. You have a warranty on a 2017 as well?